# Is there any way to set Encoding.UTF8 instance provide BOM as false

Tags: c#, xml

I know that we can create an instance of `UTF8Encoding` which doesn't provide a Unicode byte order mark by using `UTF8Encoding(false)`. But I also came across a another way of getting a reference to an `UTF8Encoding` instance is by `Encoding.UTF8`. The question is: Can we set provide BOM property of the static `Encoding.UTF8` instance as false, or it will always provide BOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding.UTF8 returns a static, default instance, which will always include the BOM

```
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Encoding UTF8
    {
      [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"), __DynamicallyInvokable] get
      {
        if (Encoding.utf8Encoding == null)
          Encoding.utf8Encoding = (Encoding) new UTF8Encoding(true);
        return Encoding.utf8Encoding;
      }
    }
```

I should note that the flag is stored in a private boolean field which you could probably set to false via reflection, but that is not a good idea for a number of reasons.

Comment: One caveat to keep in mind is that, regardless of this flag, the GetBytes method of the encoder doesn't actually include a BOM.